# Pixate Freestyle: clear styleClass property does not reset style

Tags: ios, pixate

I am using Pixate Freestyle in iOS and am adding a class to a UITableViewCell's textLabel (`cell.textLabel.styleClass = @"some-class"`). When I remove the styleClass (`cell.textLabel.styleClass = nil` or `cell.textLabel.styleClass = @""`) the style of the font remains what it was when set to @"some-class".

Any idea why this would be? Clearing styleClass on other objects works just fine. :)

Thanks.